# How to disable auto hiding of labels on Category Axis in Amchar 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, amcharts, amcharts4

In amCharts 4 column chart, labels on category axis are alternately hidden when user reduces the browser width.
By default the chart automatically hides labels to improve readability. I want to disable it.

Please refer ruining ex. codepen.io/Mishra-Praveen/pen/MWwmVbp

I am getting solution for Amchart 3 not for Amchart4.

Comment: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/positioning-axis-elements/#Setting_the_density_of_the_the_grid_labels

Answer (score 1):

```
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;
```

Increasing these numbers will mean likely sparser grid lines and related labels. Decreasing will probably result in denser grid/labels.